# Another way to make Timed FadeIn effect of objects on PageLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

Im using Visual Studio 2012 for my empty web application project and 
I made Timed fadeIn effect of objects on PageLoad  , but this way is kinda bad in my opinion.I think setTimeout functions used like this use many timers which is a waste.first timer end in 1000ms second timer end in 1500ms the whole script is "wood"

this is the aspx code i made

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id="fadeIn1" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Panel2').hide();
            $('#Image4').hide();
            $('#Image3').hide();
            $('#Image2').hide();
            $('#Label1').hide();
            $('#Panel3').hide();

            $('#Panel2').fadeIn(2000);
            setTimeout("$('#Image2').fadeIn(1000);", 1000);
            setTimeout("$('#Panel3').fadeIn(1000);", 1500);
            setTimeout("$('#Image3').fadeIn(2000);", 2000);
            setTimeout("$('#Label1').fadeIn(2000);", 2000);
            setTimeout("$('#Image4').fadeIn(2000);", 2000);



        });

    </script>
```

But What about a better script like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="fadeIn1" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Panel2').hide();
            $('#Image4').hide();
            $('#Image3').hide();
            $('#Image2').hide();
            $('#Label1').hide();
            $('#Panel3').hide();

            $('#Panel2').fadeIn(2000);
            (set delay)
            $('#Image2').fadeIn(1000);
            (set delay)
            $('#Panel3').fadeIn(1000);
            (set delay)
            $('#Image3').fadeIn(2000);
            (set delay)
            $('#Label1').fadeIn(2000);
            (set delay)
            $('#Image4').fadeIn(2000);;



        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
        $('#Panel2').fadeIn(2000, function () {
            $('#Image2').fadeIn(1000. function () {
                $('#Panel3').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
```

etc...

This will trigger the next animation after the first animation is complete without the need for additional delays

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a table of values and then just loop through the table.  Saves a lot of copied code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id="fadeIn1" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // list of items with [selector, delay time, fade time]
        var items = ["#Panel2", 0000, 1000, "#Panel3", 1500, 1000, 
                     "#Image2", 1000, 1000, "#Image3", 2000, 2000,
                     "#Image4", 2000, 2000, "#Label1", 2000, 2000];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+=3) {
            $(items[i]).hide().delay(items[i+1]).fadeIn(items[i+2]);
        }
    });

 </script>
```

In addition, you can use `.delay()` instead of `setTimeout()` for animations and you can chain the jQuery methods on the same jQuery object rather than repeating that.

---

If you control the HTML too, you could give all these items a common class and put the delay and fade time info in the HTML as data attributes.  The HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="Panel2" class="initialFade" data-delay="1000", data-fadeTime="1000"></div>
<div id="Panel3" class="initialFade" data-delay="1500", data-fadeTime="1000"></div>
...
```

Then, the jQuery would look like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id="fadeIn" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".initalFade").each(function() {
            var item = $(this).hide();
            item.delay(item.data("delay")).fadeIn(item.data("fadeTime"));
        });
    });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fade them all in, you can call all objects in a single selector and fade them all in with a function looped using the callback:

```
$(function() {
    function fadeObjs(objs) {
        if (objs.length >0) {
            var ele = objs.eq(0);
            ele.fadeIn(1000,function() {
                fadeObjs(objs.slice(1));
            });
        }
    }

    var objs = $('#Panel1,#Image2,#Panel3,#Image4,#Panel5');
    objs.hide();
    fadeObjs(objs);
});
```

If you want to delay, add a delay before the fadeIn using jQuery delay:

```
ele.delay(1000).fadeIn(1000,function() {
    fadeObjs(objs.slice(1));
});
```

If you need different fade speeds or delays, jfriends approach is good or you can make an object list with the speed and delay as params

```
$(function() {
    var objs = { '#Panel1':[1000,1000],'#Image2':[1000,1000],'#Panel3':[1500,1000],'#Image4':[1000,200],'#Panel5':[1500,500] };
    for (k in objs) {
        $(k).hide().delay(objs[k][1]).fadeIn(objs[k][0]);
    }
});
```